# iterate over a map and export vars

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, sh

this script prints out the right values but it looks like my export statement isn't correct:

```
declare -A ENVMAP=( [foo]=bar [baz]=quux [corge]=grault )
for i in "${!ENVMAP[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${ENVMAP[$i]}"
  export "$i"="${ENVMAP[$i]}"
done
```

The value gets printed correctly so the map works but the vars aren't getting exported. Whats wrong with my export statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to have these vars permanently in your user's system you could add them into your current user's DOT/BASH profile too, few steps are as follows:

***I***- Go to current user's directory by doing normal `cd`.

***II***- Then list all files including hidden ones by doing either `ls -la` or `ls -lhtr`.

***III***- Now either add these export commands in your BASH profile(in case you are on Linux/bash) or you could create your own `.profile` too(only one will be picked up at a time).

***IV***- Once you saved it then use `source .profile` or `source .bash_profile` or `. ./.profile` or `. /.bash_profile`.

Please try these and let me know if these helps you.

Answer (score 1):

How are you running the script? the exported variables are visible to the child processes of your script but not to the parent, i.e. your bash console.

Comment: how do I export them to the parent

Comment: Use `source scriptname.sh` or `. scriptname.sh` instead of running the script directly as in `./scriptname.sh`.

Comment: @mike-holt add your comment as an answer, should be the accepted one I think